# how to make a complex Json Object from UI with angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular

i have this JSON object :

> items={"departure":"New York","arrival":"California","stations":[{"station":"toto"},{"station":"titi"},{"station":"tata"}]}

i have this code which can populate this Object into the UI:

```
<div class="panel-body panelcolor">

 <div *ngIf="items?.departure">
 <span>{{items.departure}}</span> --> 
 <span *ngIf="items.stations.length > 0">
{{items.stations[0].station}}
</span>
 <span *ngIf="items.stations.length === 0">
{{items.arrival}}
    </span>

 <div class="input-group spinner">
<input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
<div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
    <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" 
type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
    <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" 
 type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
 </div>    

 <div *ngFor="let item of items.stations; let i=index, let last = last">

 <div *ngIf="!last">
  <span>{{item.station}}</span> --> <span *ngIf="items.stations[i+1]">
   {{items.stations[i+1].station}}</span>
<div class="input-group spinner">
    <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
        <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" 
   type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
        <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" 
   type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

   </div>

    <div *ngIf="items?.arrival && items?.stations.length > 0">
     <span>{{items.stations[items.stations.length-1].station}}</span> --> 
      <span>{{items.arrival}}</span>
      <div class="input-group spinner">
       <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
         <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
        <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" 
          type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
    <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" 
     type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
</div>
```

heres the UI generated :
[UI generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeu2s.png)

My question is, how can i get like this Json object bellow when i click on the submit button:

> {object:[{"name":"new york - toto","price":"the value"},{"name":"toto - mama","price":"the value"},{"name":"mama - titi","price":"the value"},
>   {"name":"titi - tata","price":"the value"},{"name":"tata - california","price":"the value"},{"name":"new york - california","price":"the value"}]}

PS:
the value mentioned in the json object is the value of the price( an integer) in UI.

Comment: i dont understand what do u mean ?

Comment: no, i want to create a new one

Comment: i want to generate a new object like mentioned above.

Comment: this is it : {object:[{"name":"new york - toto","price":"the value"},{"name":"toto - mama","price":"the value"},{"name":"mama - titi","price":"the value"}, {"name":"titi - tata","price":"the value"},{"name":"tata - california","price":"the value"},{"name":"new york - california","price":"the value"}]}

Comment: what are the onformations you need ? i can help

Comment: {"departure":"New York","arrival":"California","stations":[{"station":"toto"},{"station":"titi"},{"station":"tata"}]}

Comment: items={"departure":"New York","arrival":"California","stations":[{"station":"toto"},{"station":"titi"},{"station":"tata"}]}

Comment: is that help.??

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms. Or create a function on the submit button and pass variables from ngModel

Comment: See an example here https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/21/template-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html